# How to put the css on all php pages?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a really simple registration web page, that contains header, a registration form and a footer

Header is a header.php file that contains a menu, it's in this php file that I have put the link to CSS file.
Registration.php contains just the registration form.

The problem is when I want to modify the hight of the menu (which is in header.php, that contains the css link too) it works, but if I want to change something on the registration.php it doesn't work.

I know it's because CSS is on header.php, but how to make the css more "global" for all the pages that contain "header.php" ?

This is my header.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  title="style.css">

    <title>Safran | Home</title>    
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="menu-bloc">
        <div class="menu-wrapper menu-desktop">
            <span class="menu-logo-bloc"></span>

            <ul class="navigation-menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="registration.php">Sing up</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- MENU MOBILE -->
        <div class="menu-mobile" style="display:none;">
            <span class="menu-logo-bloc">
                <img src="assets/mobile/menu-mobile-btn.png">
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is my Registration.php page :

```
    <!-- php includes -->
    <!-- menu -->
    <?php 
        require "header.php";
    ?>
        <form method="POST" action="registration.php">
            <label div="label_registration" for="username_input">Nom d'utilisateur</label>
            <input type="text" name="username_input">

            <label div="label_registration" for="email_input">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email_input">

            <label div="label_registration" for="password_input">Mot de passe</label>
            <input type="password" name="password_input">

            <label div="label_registration" for="password_input_confirm">Confirmer le mot de passe</label>
            <input type="password" name="password_input_confirm">

            <button style="submit" class="btn btn-green btn-create" name="register_btn">créer mon compte</button>

        </form>


    </div>
    <?php require "footer.php"; ?>
```

Even if "header.php" contains CSS, and "registration.php" contains "header.php", when I try to modify for example text color of the labels from "registration.php" it doesn't work.

Comment: You will need to add a `php_include` to the css file on your registration.php file as well.

Comment: Why doesn't the html output for your registration page not include input from the header.php file? In other words, how come your registration page is constructed by your server without adding the content of the header.php file?

Comment: Thank you guys, i'm trying the php include function , but can you please check mon edit ?

Comment: If the CSS styles are applying to the menu, that means the external style sheet is loading. If the styles are not applying to the registration form, even though all files have loaded properly, that may mean that your selectors aren't matching. Check to make sure your CSS rules are properly targeting the registration form.

Answer (score 0):

Use any PHP file and write your CSS link in that file.then use require or require_once in your main PHP file you can access.

example in test.php

```
<?php 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="src file"> 
?>
```

in main.php

```
<?php 
echo "<head>";
require "test.php";
echo "</head>";             
?>
```